# How to resolve 404 Server error.Received when web is deploy on domain

Tags: asp.net, webforms

When i deploy my website got this error.
404 - File or directory not found.
The resource you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
My config code is as follow.
dont know what and where i'm missing something.However i have deploy the same project once on #somee where it work perfect.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
  </configSections>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="YourConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=juhi;Initial Catalog=kingston_DB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    <add name="kingston_DBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/CollegeModel.csdl|res://*/CollegeModel.ssdl|res://*/CollegeModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=juhi;initial catalog=kingston_DB;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;connect timeout=30;application name=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.0" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>

  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="WebDAVModule" />
    </modules>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Need suggestion to resolve this error.

Comment: did the same url work on localhost as well?

Comment: yes it is working.

Comment: there could still be a lot of reasons. Try to make sure that all the files were published.

Comment: i got no issue while publishing every thing published.

Comment: Have you configured the bindings for your domain correctly? For example: Is the domain pointing at your server correctly? Is the domain configured in IIS to point to the correct website? Is the website in IIS pointing to the correct folder on the file system? Is IIS configured to use the same default document as your application (`default.aspx` is the only default `.aspx` file out of the box, so `index.aspx` won't resolve). Are you getting the ASP.NET 404 page (yellow) or the IIS one (white)? If it's the ASP.NET one, check the path at the bottom - that may point to the problem.

Comment: By configuring Domain on IIS you mean to say it should be configure on local IIS.??

Answer (score 0):

The second connection string looks odd to me:

```
<add name="kingston_DBEntities"
    connectionString="metadata=res://*/CollegeModel.csdl|res://*/CollegeModel.ssdl|res://*/CollegeModel.msl;
    provider=System.Data.SqlClient;
    provider                                      <-- here
    connection string=&quot;                      <-- here
    data source=juhi;                             <-- here ?
    initial catalog=kingston_DB;
    integrated security=True;
    multipleactiveresultsets=True;
    connect timeout=30;
    application name=EntityFramework&quot;"       <- here
    providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```